# What are irreducible $n$-times antisymmetrized representations?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, differential-forms, spin-geometry

I came across the following statement while reading a string theory textbook:

> if $\boldsymbol{16}_s$ and $\boldsymbol{16}_c$ are the are respectively spinor and conjugate spinor representationsof $Spin(10)$, we have the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition
> $$\boldsymbol{16}_s\otimes\boldsymbol{16}_c = [0]\oplus[2]\oplus[4]$$
> where $[n]$ denotes the irreducible $n$-times antisymmetrized representation of $Spin(10)$, which from a field theoretic point of view correspond to $n$-forms.

I don't understand what exactly are those antisymmetrized representations. What is the general definition ? In what way does it corresponds to forms ?

Comment: The statement is slightly imprecise: I'd describe $[n]$ as the representation $\bigwedge^n \Bbb V$ of $n$-vectors, where $\Bbb V$ is the irreducible $10$-dimensional representation of $\operatorname{Spin}(10)$, i.e., the representation that factors through the defining representation of $\operatorname{SO}(10)$. In particular, the dimension of $[0] \oplus [2] \oplus [4]$ is ${{10} \choose 0} + {{10} \choose 2} + {{10} \choose 4} = 1 + 45 + 210 = 256$, which coincides with the dimension of $16 \cdot 16$ of $\textbf{16}_s \otimes \textbf{16}_c$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much @TravisWillse , this exactly what I wanted to know. Juste a precision, what exactly do you mean by "the representation that factors through the defining representation of SO(10)" ?

Comment: I've expanded my comment into an answer; in particular the first sentence addresses your question, but I'm happy to clarify further as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $SO(10) \to GL(\Bbb V)$ (or just $\Bbb V$) denote the defining (i.e., irreducible, $10$-dimensional) representation of $SO(10)$, and by slight abuse of notation also denote by $\Bbb V$ the representation
$$Spin(10) \to SO(10) \to GL(\Bbb V)$$
of $Spin(10)$, where $Spin(10) \to SO(10)$ is the usual $2 : 1$ covering map. This representation is the first fundamental representation, i.e., the one with highest weight $[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]$.

The notation $[k]$ indicates the $k$th alternating power, $\bigwedge^k \Bbb V$ of $\Bbb V$: Explicitly, the underlying vector space is the space of $k$-vectors on $\Bbb V$, i.e., alternating (contravariant) $k$-tensors on $\Bbb V$ (thus $\dim [k] = \dim \bigwedge^k \,\Bbb V = {10 \choose k}$), and the (linear) action is characterized by the formula
$$g \cdot (v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k) := (g \cdot v_1) \wedge \cdots \wedge (g \cdot v_k) .$$ (On the right-hand side, $\cdot$ denotes the action of the representation $Spin(10) \to GL(\Bbb V)$.)

We can use the inner product fixed on $\Bbb V$ fixed by $Spin(10)$ to raise and lower indices of tensors on $\Bbb V$, which in particular defines natural isomorphisms $\bigwedge^k \Bbb V \cong \bigwedge^k \Bbb V^*$. So we can just as well identify $[k]$ with the representation $\bigwedge^k \Bbb V^*$ of $k$-forms, i.e., alternating (covariant) $k$-tensors, on $\Bbb V$.

In summary, the representations $[k]$ are

$$\begin{array}{cccrl}
\hline
&& \textrm{highest weight} & \dim & \textrm{name}\\
\hline
[0] & \Bbb R & [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] & 1 & \textrm{trivial}\\
[1] & \Bbb V & [1, 0, 0, 0, 0] & 10 & \textrm{defining}\\
[2] & \bigwedge^2 \Bbb V & [0,1,0,0,0] & 45 & \textrm{alternating $2$-tensor}\\
[3] & \bigwedge^3 \Bbb V & [0,0,1,0,0] & 120 & \textrm{alternating $3$-tensor}\\
[4] & \bigwedge^4 \Bbb V & [0,0,0,1,1] & 210 & \textrm{alternating $4$-tensor}\\
[5] & \bigwedge^5 \Bbb V & \ast & 252 & \textrm{alternating $5$-tensor}\\
\hline
\end{array} .$$

For $0 \leq k \leq 10$, the [Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) $\ast : \bigwedge^{10 - k} \Bbb V \stackrel{\cong}{\to} \bigwedge^k \Bbb V$ defines an isomorphism $[10 - k] \cong [k]$, so the above table exhausts all of the representations $[k]$ up to isomorphism. In particular, for $k = 5$ the $\ast$ is a (nontrivial) involution of $\bigwedge^5 \Bbb V$, so that representation is not irreducible: It decomposes into the direct sum of the (in fact, irreducible) $\pm 1$-eigenspaces $\bigwedge^5_\pm \Bbb V$ of $\ast$, both of which have have dimension $126$. Here $\bigwedge^5_\pm \Bbb V$ are the representations of self-dual and anti-self-dual $5$-forms. In highest-weight notation they are $[0,0,0,2,0]$ and $[0,0,0,0,2]$, respectively.

As expected, $$\dim ([0] \oplus [2] \oplus [4]) = 1 + 45 + 210 = 256 = 16 \times 16 = \dim ({\bf 16}_s \otimes {\bf 16}_c) .$$

The above claims hold, mutatis mutandis, for the representations of alternating $k$-tensors for all groups $Spin(2 m)$, at least for $m \geq 3$; more adjustments need to be made for the groups $Spin(n)$ with $n$ odd.